# Criterion for proving that a quotient space is finite dimensional

Tags: linear-algebra, quotient-spaces

In the book of Introductory Real Analysis of Kolmogorov and Fomin (page 122), there is some theorem about the dimension of quotient spaces. Let $L$ be vector space and $L'$ be a vector subspace. It says that $L/L'$ (the quotient space) is finite dimensional (with dimension $n$) if and only if any $x \in L$ can be written as:

$$x= \mu_1 x_1 + ... \mu_n x_n + y$$

where $x_i \notin L'$, $y \in L'$.

My question is then the following: Is this equivalent to saying that the quotient space is finite dimensional if and only if $L-L'$ (the complement of $L'$) is finite dimensional? It seems right but I am struggling proving it. Thanks!

Comment: Another interpretation is that there exists a projection onto a subspace spanned by a finite number of vectors. The kernel and the image of that projection will be orthogonal compliments and the kernel does not have to be finite dimensional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is true depending on your definitions.  If you mean the **set theoretic complement** $L-L'$, which is to say the set of all vectors $v \in L$ which are not in $L'$, then no.    The set theoretic complement is not a vector subspace of $L$, and hence cannot be assigned a vector space dimension.  If you mean a **vector space complement** of $L'$ in $L$, which is to say a subspace $L''$ of $L$ such that $L$ is the direct sum of $L'$ and $L''$, then this is true.

Note that it is really more correct to say *a* (vector space) complement of a subspace rather than *the* complement.  This is because complements are far from unique.  For example, if $L$ is the plane $\mathbb R^2$, and $L'$ is a one-dimensional subspace of $L$ (that is, a line passing through the origin), then every other line passing through the origin is a complement of $L'$ in $L$.

Anyway, if $L''$ is a complement of $L'$ in $L$, then $L''$ is isomorphic  to the quotient vector space $L/L'$, an isomorphism being given by sending any $v \in L''$ to the coset $v + L'$ in $L/L'$.  Hence $L/L'$ is finite dimensional if and only if $L''$ is.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am interested particularly in the case of the Cokernel. I have some continuous linear map $T: X \to Y$, and would like to show that the $Y / Im T$ is finite dimensional. I have inifinitely many linearly independent elements in the "set theoretic" complement, i.e. that are not in $Im T$. So I would need to show that they also lie in the "vector space" complement. But what is such a space?

Comment: @Sarah it's called the orthogonal compliment. It will be the set of all vectors orthogonal to the subspace. You might find it instructive to prove this is a subspace and that any vector in the full sapce can be decomposed into the sum of a vector from each subspace.

Comment: @Sarah you should maybe ask a new question to try to understand what is a vector space complement.

Comment: Dear @D_S coudl you please clarify: if I find infinitely many linearly independent elements that are not in the image, then doesn't this guarantee already that the Cokernel is inifinite dimensional? Because if $B$ is a basis of $Y$ and $D_1 \subset Y$ a basis of the $Im T$, then these inifinte linearly independent of elements that I speak must be in $D_2:=D - D_1$ (here - being the actual set theoretic meaning of a complement), right?

Comment: "if I find infinitely many linearly independent elements that are not in the image, then doesn't this guarantee already that the Cokernel is inifinite dimensional?"  What image?  What map?

Comment: I am refering to my first comment. The image of a linear map $T$ between two vector spaces.